# Histogram equalization: Not getting required output image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to implement histogram equalization function myself, but not getting required output image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
%matplotlib inline

def freq(lst):
    d = {}
    for i in lst:
        for j in i:
            if d.get(j):
                d[j] += 1
            else:
                d[j] = 1

    return d
def probability(d,total_pixels):
    l = {}
    for i in range(256):
        value = d.get(i)
        if value != None:
            l[i] = value/total_pixels
    return l
def equalizer(d, l):
    f_dic = {}
    last_sum = 0
    for i in range(l):
        if d.get(i):
            prob = d.get(i)
            last_sum = last_sum+((l-1)*prob)
            f_dic[i] = math.floor(last_sum)
    return f_dic
def replace_values(f_dic, img):
    print(f_dic)
    for i in range(len(img)):
        for j in range(len(img)):
            vv = f_dic.get(img[i][j])
            if vv != None:
                img[i][j] = vv
    return img
def histogramEqualization(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    freqq = freq(img)
    area = img.shape
    total_pixels = area[0]*area[1]
    prob = probability(freqq, total_pixels)
    f_dic = equalizer(prob,len(img))
    new_img = replace_values(f_dic,img)
    return new_img
pollen_dark = cv2.imread("/home/ahmed/Downloads/dip/DIP_A1_Fall2019/pollen_dark.tif")
new = histogramEqualization(pollen_dark)
plt.imshow(new, cmap='gray')
```

I am getting this image:
[image: output_image]

input image is this:
[image: input_image]

required output image is:
[image: required_output_image].
Formula implementing to solve this problem

[image: Formula implementing]

Comment: You are overflowing on your calculations somewhere. Make your intermediate values z as larger type to avoid this (computing with 8-bit ints is not good).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'd agree that computing with 8-bit ints is dangerous, but this is using Python `int`s most of the time, and there is no overflowing there. The funny results come from the a buggy parameter / formula in `equalizer()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this with NumPy is to use `np.unique()` to find the values to modify, and their probability distribution function (pdf) which is basically a histogram. This can be used to generate the corresponding normalized values, according to the cumulative distribution function (cdf) obtained from `np.cumsum()` on the pdf, using the formula:

`round((cdf - min_cdf) / (num_voxels - min_cdf) * (depth - 1))`

The whole idea (as well as the formula) is pictorially described nicely in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Implementation).

This is typically a cleaner approach than looping through the array:

```
DEPTH = 2 ** 8


def hist_equalization(arr, depth=DEPTH):
    vals, pdf = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
    min_cdf = min(cdf)
    new_vals = (
        np.round((cdf - min_cdf) / (arr.size - min_cdf) * (depth - 1))
        .astype(int))
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i, val in enumerate(vals):
        result[np.nonzero(arr == val)] = new_vals[i]
    return result


plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=DEPTH - 1)
plt.imshow(hist_equalization(arr), cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=DEPTH - 1)
```

Input:

[image: img_input]

Output:

[image: img_output]

(The full script is available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FxeGwFM2wr36sRWSsatsuQyVX4nK92ao). Note that I used `PIL` instead of `cv` for I/O for convenience, but it is irrelevant to the problem.)

---

## EDIT

There are a number of glitches (some less serious, some more serious) here and there in your code, but the one that is preventing you from getting the correct result is that `equalizer()` is fundamentally wrong.

If you replace your version of `equalizer()` with:

```
def equalizer(pdf, l, depth=2 ** 8):
    min_cdf = pdf[min(pdf)]
    result = {}
    accumulator = 0
    for k, v in sorted(pdf.items()):
        accumulator += v
        result[k] = int(round((accumulator - min_cdf) / (l - min_cdf) * (depth - 1)))     
    return result
```

to be called with:

```
f_dic = equalizer(freqq, total_pixels)
```

Then the rest of your code should work.
Note that `probability()` is completely unnecessary and you do really need `total_pixels` (or `img.size`), as `len(img)` applied to a N-dimensional array will give you its length **along the 0-th dimension**, not the total number of pixels.

(This is also included [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FxeGwFM2wr36sRWSsatsuQyVX4nK92ao).)

Comment: This works. But I am interested in finding out what is wrong with my code. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Mrcreamio see edits, but please beware that the vectorized version as proposed above is **MUCH** faster and cleaner than the minimal edits required to fix your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I changed `f_dic = equalizer(prob,len(img))` with `f_dic = equalizer(prob,2**8)` and it worked. see the edit above. I added the formula, I was trying to implement.

Comment: @Mrcreamio Good that you found the issue. It would have been helpful to get the math you were trying to implement in your original code right away. I do not see an immediate way of writing this new formula in vectorized form, though.